# find_element_by_xpath is not working for TextView containing text with square brackets

Tags: android, python, xpath, appium

in android app I have a `TextView` with text as `"[PC]"`.

and I am trying to find that text using appium in python like following

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//TextView[@text='[PC]']").
```

but it gives error Message:

```
u'An error occurred while searching for an element by XPath.'
```

Comment: try self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//TextView[@text='PC']")

Comment: Could you please show us an example of your XML. Your XPath expresion is valid but you may for exemple have namespaces issues.

Comment: I have a simple TextView in xml
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[PC]" />